# Running multiple shell scripts in parallel and in background

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, benchmarking, ycsb

I have some YCSB Data load scripts which runs in background

data_load.sh:

```
nohup ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load1_output.txt &

nohup ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load2_output.txt &

nohup ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load3_output.txt &
```

And Some YCSB Run Scripts too which looks like this:

Read_test.sh:

```
nohup ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read1_output.txt &

nohup ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read2_output.txt &

nohup ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read3_output.txt &
```

If I run them individually, they would run in background and in parallel.

But how to automate this or write a script which will call both this scripts one after another and will wait for 1st one to finish before going to the next script ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's wrong with `data_load.sh; Read_test.sh`?

Comment: It doesn't wait for data_load to finish and start Read_test.sh.

Comment: Add `wait` to the end of `data_load.sh`

Comment: In that case, you might be able to get this just by adding the line `wait` to the end of your first script.

Comment: @GrishaLevit: Good Point. But I am not sure how long the first script will take to complete.

Comment: @DeepjyotiSaha that's exactly the point. `wait` will wait for however long it takes for all the background jobs to finish.  Which is what you asked for: *"call both this scripts one after another and will wait for 1st one to finish"*

Comment: @GrishaLevit: As I am using both 'nohup' and '&' in data_load script, so all the commands are running in background. So, if I use wait after first script, it doesn't help and starts the second script without waiting for the first to finish.

Comment: My suggestion was not to wait *after* the first script, but to wait *in* the first script.

Answer (score 1):

You can either modify your first script to have a `wait` at the end, *or* you can have a parent script `source` the first script and `wait`.

```
source ./data_load.sh
wait
./Read_test.sh
```

By `source`-ing the child script, jobs that it creates are actually going to be jobs of the main script, enabling you to `wait` for them.

<sup>The `wait` builtin with no arguments will wait until all background jobs are done, after which execution will proceed to the next command</sup>

Comment: Thanks @grisha Levit. The wait command works perfectly and solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` in parallel mode.

```
$ echo {1..4} | xargs -n1 -P 4 echo "potato"
potato 1
potato 4
potato 3
potato 2
```

This piped command says "take the inpiped input, peel off one thing at a time, into 4 threads, and echo it with the string 'potato'."

There's also [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/), which some folks swear by -- though the learning curve and fact that it's no better than xargs for my use cases (and the fact that it doesn't come pre-installed on my distro) have kept me from learning too much about it.

Comment: Can you please tell me what has to be done in my case ? How do I run this two scripts which contains some commands in parallel ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'll elaborate on a p's answer:

load_and_read.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

load_commands='ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load1_output.txt
ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load2_output.txt
ycsb load couchbase2 -s -P workloada -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > load3_output.txt'
echo "$load_commands" | xargs -P3

read_commands='ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read1_output.txt
ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read2_output.txt
ycsb run couchbase2 -s -P workloadc -p couchbase.bucket=poc -threads 30 .. > read3_output.txt'
echo "$read_commands" | xargs -P3
```

use `nohup ./load_and_read.sh &` to run the entire script in the background. the first `echo "$cmds" | xargs -P3` runs the three load commands in parallel, then, after those three finish, the second one runs the three read commands in parallel.